# Update div in smarty template with jQuery

Tags: jquery, web, smarty

I am trying to replace the content of a div in a smarty template based on what link a user clicks on.

**Problem:** When I click on the link, the page to which the href points opens in the same window in the browser, instead of overwriting the content in just one part of the page.

--> For reference, [this](http://tox.sinaiem.org/notebook.php) is the web page.

The following is my jQuery code:

```
 $('#notes').click(function(evt)
 {
    $('#main').html(($this).attr('href'));
    evt.preventDefault();
 });
```

**Updated jQuery code based on FYE's suggestion**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        $('#notes').click(function(evt)
            {   
                $('#main').append(get(($(this).attr('href'))));
                evt.preventDefault();
            });

    });
```

It's in a script tag in the head of the template.

**Source of hrefs:**

```
 {block name=sidebar}
      <p class="nav-header" id="notes">Notes</p>
        {foreach $lectures as $lecture}
            <a href={$lecture} class="notes">{$lecture@key}</a><br>
         {/foreach}
 {/block}
```

**Target:**

```
  {block name=body}
      <div id="main">
          Bob
      </div>
 {/block}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, i think `jQuery.html()` isn't used like this, it will replace the contents of your div with the address of the link, not its content.

You should use an AJAX method like `jQuery.ajax()` or `jQuery.get()` to get the contents, and then manually replace it with `append()` or `appendTo()`

But to prevent the page from opening, `evt.preventDefault()` should do the work, try `return false;` instead, but i'm not sure.

Comment: Replacing `.html` with `.get` and chaining that to `.append` doesn't work. :-/. Wrapping everything in `.ready` (as I've indicated) doesn't help. :-/. I think what's happening is that when I click on the link the JavaScript isn't executing at all. When I stuck `alert('hi')` above the `$('#main')...` I didn't see anything on the console.

Comment: Do you have console errors?

Also `get` isn't used like this neither, go check [link](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) for some examples

Comment: I'm able to get console errors, because I was listening to the wrong element for the click. (It should be `$('a')`). Updated code too-- still missing something about getting the content of that URL. (Thanks for your continued help.)

Comment: As I was saying, you're using `$.get()` the wrong way.

`$.get($(this).attr('href'), function(data) {
  $('#main').append(data);
});`

should be ok. Don't forget to read the jQuery documentation, it's really detailed. No problem by the way :)